# Better Call /me maybe?

Tags: support, users, authentication

I am using implicit OAuth 2.0 flow, hence requesting for a token first.

Now when I want to know which user has logged in, I have to make request to `/me` endpoint to get all of the data about the user, however it requires me to know the site that user has registered at.

When doing request with, say, a site that user hasn't registered to, I get empty list of items. This way I'd either have to use brute force requests until I actually manage to guess the correct website for the user OR I have to present user with selection of sites and as her to choose the correct site.

Is there a way for me to get all user info without knowing which site to pass to `/me` endpoint? Am I missing something?

Comment: did you figure a solution ?